# Flash AS3, how to index a hashmap with integer keys

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, search, indexing, timestamp

Here's the deal.

Right now I have a dictionary of game states

```
history = new Dictionary();
```

Each state's `key` being a timestamp(int)

```
history[100] = currentState;
history[500] = currentState;
history[699] = currentState;
```

My question is, how can I find the most recent game state. Let's say I want to know what the state was like at `670`, I want the most recent history that's not greater than `670` (I don't want to show the future). This would be `history[500]`.

Right now I'm looping through every key, to find the most recent one. Is there some way I can index these timestamps, so I can search faster than linear time? (I'll have a lot of keys!) Maybe I don't want a dictionary?

Comment: You should provide more information such as your performance constraints, how many times you modify the list of states, how many times you read it, etc. For example, if you read the list more often than you modify it, it may be a good idea to keep it sorted.

Comment: @sch Good points. But it's always sorted(if I were to change it, I would make a new history, history can't change), I just don't know how to take advantage of that fact!

Comment: Well, the interval between keys doesn't grow with the length of the list. If you just search backward from the point of interest (e.g. 670,  669, 668...), performance should be more than reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a binary search (divide and conquer) approach where you save the states in a sorted array, and you recursively:

1. divide the array into two halves
2. if the array contains one item, return that item
3. determine which half would contain the correct result
4. go to step 1

This should find the result in logarithmic time. (Note that log<sub>2</sub>(1,000) ~ 10 and log<sub>2</sub>(10,000) ~ 13)

---

Here is a draft (and non tested) implementation:

```
class HistoryEntry
{
    public var timestamp:int;
    public var state:GameState;

    public function HistoryEntry(timestamp:int, state:GameState)
    {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.state = state;
    }
}

class History
{
    private var states:Array;

    public function History()
    {
        super();
        states = [];
    }

    public function addState(state:State):void
    {
        var timestamp:int = getTimer();
        var entry:HistoryEntry = new HistoryEntry(timestamp, state);
        states.push(entry);
    }

    public function getStateBefore(timestamp:int):State
    {
        return doGetStateBefore(timestamp, 0, states.length - 1);
    }

    // Recursive function
    private function doGetStateBefore(timestamp:int, beginIndex:int, endIndex:int):State
    {
        if (beginIndex == endIndex) {
            return states[beginIndex];
        }

        var beginEntry:HistoryEntry = states[beginIndex];
        var endEntry:HistoryEntry = states[endIndex];
        if (beginEntry.timestamp == timestamp) {
            return beginEntry.state;
        }
        if (endEntry.timestamp == timestamp) {
            return endEntry.state;
        }

        var middleIndex:int = (beginIndex + endIndex) / 2;
        var middleEntry:HistoryEntry = states[middleIndex];
        if (midleEntry.timestamp >= timestamp) {
            return doGetStateBefore(timestamp, beginIndex, middleIndex);
        } else {
            return doGetStateBefore(timestamp, middleIndex + 1, endIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I introduced the class `HistoryEntry` so that I get typed objects from the array because using dynamic objects will have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: +1 I was typing a similar answer... [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Just a hunch,  he might find the iterative version (see link) easier since he is not looking for an exact match.

Comment: This is really awesome. I'm not sure that it'll always work though? Because an exact match doesn't always exist, in that case I want the closest timestamp, that's not greater than the timestamp searched on. I'll try it out and see what happens. I'm sure binary search is what I want though, not hash maps.

Comment: If there is no exact match, the search will stop when there is only one item left (see the if condition at the beginning of `doGetStateBefore`). That item is supposed to be the item with the nearest timestamp if the implementation is correct.